# C-Programming: What happens if I increment an Arraypointer while passing it as an argument

Tags: c

Will this work? 
I expect

```
foo(myArraypointer + 10);
```

be the same as

```
foo( &(myArraypointer[10]));
```

will this be treated as same for most compilers? Is this considered good or bad practice and why? What could go wrong?

Comment: It is the same, period. Not "for the most compilers". The style is opinion based.

Comment: Note about post text: With `char myArray[10];
  char (*myArraypointer)[10] = &myArray`,   `foo(myArray + 1)` "adding 1 to an Array", as in the title, is not the same as code  `foo(myArraypointer + 1)`, adding 1 to an _array pointer_.  The first adds 1 (sizeof element), the 2nd adds 10 (sizeof array).

Comment: Changed the title to be consistent with the question. The other answers contradict your comment, are you sure about the diffrence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any pointer or array `a` and index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is equal to `*(a + i)`. That means that `&a[i]` is equal to `&*(a + i)`, where the last can be shortened to `a + i`.

Comment: and also `i[a]`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Well, that would be a bad style in all adequate opinions :)

Comment: The famous book Introduction to Algorithms uses the notation `index[Array]` in its pseudo code, it is very cute :D

Comment: Well that was certainly fast. Accepted. Wow, thats some exotic notation...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Would it use `0[a]` to indicate the first element? o_O

Comment: ah sorry I didn't recall correctly. It was just that length of an array was coded as `length[A]` while indexing would have been `A[0]` for example. In later editions they now seem to use `A.length` instead.

Comment: I wonder why this error `error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector` is issued when neither `a` or `i` are pointers only, and not issued for one of them being a pointer. Even though in `i[a]` the  subscripted value is neither as well.

Answer (score 2):

They are exactly the same as required by the C standard. Note that the compiler must not evaluate the array index before taking its address: i.e. the expression is well defined even if the array elements are not initialised.

I prefer the first one though. It's clearer and is friendlier to C++ code which might have overloaded the address of operator for your type. And the non-initialised point I've already made is really one for the pub quiz.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are same as in the first one `foo(myArraypointer + 10);` it access `myArraypointer` which is the base address of variable and +10 will increment the address to 10th position from base address. 
Incrementing or decrementing address of a pointer depends upon the data type of the pointer Variable. i.e. if pointer is character type it'll increment/decrements by 1. 
If `myArraypointer` points to a character whose address is 1000, then increment by one will point to the location 1001 but if `myArraypointer` points to an integer whose address is 1000, then increment by one will point to the location 1002(1000 + 2). Like this for float also.